# Using same data bound function for two gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where I work there is a page with two grid views and both gridviews use the same binding function and there is a problem because of it.. so in the function it has a foreach row for the gridview but it only does it for one gridview as you will see in the code, how can I make it so that it iterates throw the gridviews in the page? therea are two one named GridView1 and the other GridView2, but both use the same data bind. I want to reduce the code.. see below:

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
             //somecode related to GridView1
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            //somecode related to GeidView2
        }
      }
```

Now the code in each foreach is extensive, and basically is the same code for both cases.. how can i do this more efficiently instead of having the same code in the foreach's for each one of the gridviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `sender` object that is passed to the event handler.  This is a reference to the object that raised the event.

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    GridView CurrentGv = (GridView)sender;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in CurrentGv.Rows) 
    { 
         //somecode related to BOTH GridViews
    } 
}
```